# Trying to show that columns of Fourier matrix are eigenvectors

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform, fourier-restriction

I posted a picture since the syntax for this one seems quite complex:

[image]

I found this: [Discrete Fourier Transform - proof that columns of matrix are orthogonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357865/discrete-fourier-transform-proof-that-columns-of-matrix-are-orthogonal) which only shows that are orthogonal. In my case I need to show that they are eigenvectors. I have no idea how show this

Comment: If you have a matrix $A$ and a vector $x$, how do you show that $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$?  Easy: just calculate $Ax$, and show that the result is a multiple of $x$.

Comment: Have you at least tried to do that much?  If so, where are you getting stuck?

Comment: So you're saying to pick a random vector $x$, multiply it by A and then show the result is a multiple of A?

Comment: Not a **random** vector: take $x$ to be a column vector from $F_n$.

Comment: @john Hi john, Did you find a simpler answer to this question? It's important to me, I would be so grateful if you help me with it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be the cyclic shift operator. Notice that $A = -S^{-1} +2S^0 - S$. The fact that the discrete Fourier basis vectors are eigenvectors of $A$ now follows from the fact that they are eigenvectors of $S$. (And the whole point of the discrete Fourier basis vectors is that they are eigenvectors of $S$.)

A similar argument shows that the discrete Fourier basis vectors are eigenvectors for any convolution operator.